# How do you switch between Firestore emulator and cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, gcloud, firebase-cli

I am setting up a new machine to do Firebase/Firestore/Functions development. There are three ways for me to interact with Firestore:

- Deploy my Functions to the cloud, so both Functions & Firestore are running remotely there.
- Run Functions locally (firebase serve --only functions), which hosts the functions locally, but reads/writes to the Cloud Firestore
- Run Firestore Emulator AND Functions locally, which hosts the functions locally AND Firestore locally (so triggers work)

I started installing everything from scratch and have ended up in an in-between state.

- I can successfully deploy my Functions to the Cloud and things work, but this slows cycle times.
- I can run the Firestore emulator and serve Functions locally. Things appear to work, but I do not know how to browse the Firestore emulator to confirm that documents are being written. Console logs appear to confirm it is working, but I would like to peak under the covers.
- When I serve Functions locally (without the Firestore emulator), they just hang - silently failing to reach the Cloud Firestore. I cannot figure out what it is trying to do that is failing.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to navigate/browse the emulator document collections? The emulator home page at http://localhost:8080 simply shows 'ok'
2. How can I debug why the local functions server cannot reach the Cloud Firestore?
3. Is there some configuration required to switch back and forth between having the local Functions server relying on the Emulator vs. the Cloud Firestore?

Answer (score -1):

As far as firebase emulators are considered, different services of firebase run at different ports. When you kick it off with the command `firebase emulators:start`, it prints out a table with the information of what services running which port. Refer the image below

[image: emulator start command standard output]

When you click and open the emulator UI URL, you can do all the things which you can do in the actual remote console. I have provided the screen shot below

[image]

Its as simple as that, let me know if this answers your question